# How do I debug apache restarting a mod_wsgi process?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

How can I debug apache to understand why it's restarting a mod_wsgi process? And how can this happen?

I have a django application running Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) with mod_wsgi - single process, multi-threaded.  I had messages in my python log file which only happen when the process first initializes - only after I manually restart apache... but apache hadn't been restarted.  I didn't see anything in the apache access / error logs either.  Does apache ever restart a process on it's own?

A short time later, apache basically stopped servicing any requests - as if it had hung or crashed, and I needed to restart apache.

Never seen this before - is there anything I can monitor to deep dive into the state of apache?

Relevant parts of config look like this:

```
###  Apache/sites-enabled/main.wsgi:
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
    SSLCACertificateFile ...

    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /myproject/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /myproject/scripts>
        <Files myapp.wsgi>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


####  /myproject/scripts/myapp.wsgi:
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/myproject')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

In addition to the custom initialization log entries indicating the process restarted, I noticed the following in the apache-error.log:

```
[Mon Sep 15 17:43:35 2014] [core:error] [pid 2801:tid 140079485876000] [client 111.111.111.111:64444] End of script output before headers: myapp.wsgi, referer: https://mysite.com/login.html
```

Comment: Please post you apache site wsgi config. And the logs you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Apache LogLevel to 'info':

```
LogLevel info
```

This will cause mod_wsgi to output more messages about the restart of daemon processes.

Provide the log messages for that.

Also ensure that nothing is running in embedded mode by mistake.

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

If your application is hanging, then the issue may be that you are using Python modules that do not work in Python sub interpreters. To combat that, set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

For details about this see:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

You might also watch:

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

It explains a lot about how Apache can restart processes if using embedded mode and the problems that can cause.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce my error, but your answer is just what I was looking for - thank you!